# How to aggregate objects of different classes like Copula, lm in a single object while preserving their orginal classes and call them in a loop in R?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, regression, probability

I have few objects of class RVineMatrix and copula families. I need to call every combination of two of these objects and compare them in a function.  Of course I can select combinations of two manually without using a loop, but it would be much easier through two "for" loops. I aggregated all the objects in a list and then called them in two loops as the elements of that list, but then realised in that way their classes would changed to "list".

```
AllCopula=list(RVM1,RVM2, RVM3,RVM4)


for (ic in 1:size(AllCopula)[2]){
for (ic2 in 1:size(AllCopula)[2]){
TestTable[ic,ic2]<- TestCopula(DesingData,AllCopula[ic],AllCopula[ic2])
}
}
```

Any help would be appropriated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

list should preserve the original classes, as you can see in this example code:

```
> require(xts)
> test <- xts(NA, Sys.Date())
> vec1 <- seq(1:10)
> typeof(test)
[1] "logical"
> typeof(vec1)
[1] "integer"
> l <- list(test, vec1)
> typeof(l)
[1] "list"
> typeof(l[1])
[1] "list"
> typeof(l[[1]])
[1] "logical"
> typeof(l[[2]])
```

Hence, you just have to get the right element from the list in your loop, try double brackets [[]].